# Form submit to Pretty URL - Empty post data

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess

I am sending all requests to index.php excluding some directories using .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vendor [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Public_Image [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resource [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node_modules [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php [L]
```

Now, when I submit a form from `/admin/login` to `/admin/login/process`

```
<form class="ui large form" method="post" action="/admin/login/process">
...
</form>
```

The POST values in `/admin/login/process` are EMPTY.

I also tried with `/admin/login/process/` as the action, as suggested by some other answer on Stack Overflow. But same result, POST values are empty.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

Any suggestions or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file located? Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? The directives you have posted don't appear to apply to a URL of the form `/admin/login/process`, so how is this being routed?

Comment: _Aside:_ You probably should be using the `NC` on your `RewriteCond` directives in this instance, unless your _server_ is case-insensitive?